# PIVOT rows to columns with more than 1 value returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am currently working on a system that has 2 tables set up like so:

```
Table_1
-------
ID
Table2ID
Value



Table_2
--------
ID
ColumnName
```

Some mock results from each table:

```
Table_1

Table2ID   |   Value
---------------
1          |   ABCD
1          |   EFGH
1          |   IJKL
2          |   MNOP
2          |   QRST
2          |   UVWX


Table_2

ID   |   ColumnName
--------------------
1    |   First_Set
2    |   Second_Set
```

So, I have the following query, attempting to turn Table_2's row results into columns

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT B.ColumnName, A.Value
FROM Table_1 AS A 
     INNER JOIN Table_2 AS B ON A.Table2ID = B.ID
     ) AS P
   PIVOT
   (
       min(P.Value)
       for P.ColumnName in ([First_Set], [Second_Set])
   ) AS PIV
```

The problem is that, as it's written, I get back a single result. My returned value would be something like this:

```
    First_Set  |  Second_Set
    -------------------------
    ABCD       |  MNOP
```

What I want is ALL of the result for each column, but I haven't been able to find a method of using PIVOT that lets me do that.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to turn rows into columns and then receive multiple results for each column?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PIVOT requires the use of an aggregate function to get the result, in your case you are using the `min` function which, in your query, will return only one value for `First_Set` and `Second_Set`.  I would suggest including a column that will be used to keep the rows distinct when applying the PIVOT.

For your data, I would suggest using `row_number()` to generate a unique value for each item in the sets.  This value will then be used in the grouping aspect of the PIVOT:

```
SELECT [First_Set], [Second_Set]
FROM
(
  SELECT B.ColumnName, A.Value
    , row_number() over(partition by a.Table2ID
                        order by a.Value) seq
  FROM Table_1 AS A 
  INNER JOIN Table_2 AS B 
    ON A.Table2ID = B.ID
) AS P
PIVOT
(
  min(P.Value)
  for P.ColumnName in ([First_Set], [Second_Set])
) AS PIV;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75245/5).  This will give a result:

```
| FIRST_SET | SECOND_SET |
|      ABCD |       MNOP |
|      EFGH |       QRST |
|      IJKL |       UVWX |
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you very much for your help :) I'd give you double upvotes for showing me sql fiddle! lol

Comment: @user1548103 You are welcome, you provided great details to answer the question.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I don't know Excel's pivot functionality, so you'd have to try it to see.

Comment: already tried a lot and came up to SQL to have it work as I would expect ;)