# Transpose rows into columns in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

How do I turn this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Have you heard about pivot query?

Comment: No I have not. Can it be useful in my case?

Comment: @bluefeet D'Oh. Deleted my comment! But I'm quiet sure that this questions has been answered often here on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is very similar to this one [PIVOT rows to columns with more than 1 value returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851588/pivot-rows-to-columns-with-more-than-1-value-returned), where you need to aggregate string data from rows into columns.  I will modify that answer to demonstrate how you can convert your data to your final result.

Since you are aggregating string values, you will need to apply either the `min()` or `max()` aggregate function, but in order to get the final result to display more than one row you need something to force the multiple rows.

In order to do this you will want to use `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence number for each `parameter` in the `name`.  When you apply the PIVOT function, this number will be used in the grouping and you will generate multiple rows:

```
select Car, Truck, Bicycle
from
(
  select vt.name, vp.parameter,
    row_number() over(partition by vt.name
                      order by vt.id) seq
  from vehicle_types vt
  left join vehicle_parameters vp
    on vt.id = vp.vehicletype
) d
pivot
(
  max(parameter)
  for name in (Car, Truck, Bicycle)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac184/3).

This could also be written using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'Car' then parameter end) Car,
  max(case when name = 'Truck' then parameter end) Truck,
  max(case when name = 'Bicycle' then parameter end) Bicycle
from
(
  select vt.name, vp.parameter,
    row_number() over(partition by vt.name
                      order by vt.id) seq
  from vehicle_types vt
  left join vehicle_parameters vp
    on vt.id = vp.vehicletype
) d
group by seq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac184/4).

The above two versions are great if you have a known number of names, then you can hard-code the query but if you don't then you will have to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from vehicle_types
                    group by id, name
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select vt.name, vp.parameter,
                  row_number() over(partition by vt.name
                                    order by vt.id) seq
                from vehicle_types vt
                left join vehicle_parameters vp
                  on vt.id = vp.vehicletype
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(parameter)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac184/6). All versions give a result:

```
|    CAR |            TRUCK |    BICYCLE |
|--------|------------------|------------|
|   make |          maxload |      frame |
|   year | hasconcretemixer |     isroad |
| engine |           (null) | ismountain |
```

Comment: I liked your first answer than second because second one is hard coded. What if he has more rows in vehicle_type table.

Comment: @AshReva I updated my answer to include a dynamic sql version if there are unknown `vehicletypes`

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Now I need to understand what it actually does :)