# How to convert the table rows in form of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I am having two tables and I want to generate the report where all the rows will be in single line.

`tbl_Questions`:

```
Id  Name
---------
1   Abc
2   Cde
3   xyz
4   MMM
```

`tbl_Reponses`:

```
Id  QuestionId   Values
------------------------
1      1           123
2      2           456
3      3           444
```

Now I want to get a query which will show sometime like this in result.

```
Id Abc Cde xyz MMM
-------------------
1  123 456 444
```

How can I get this through a query ?

Comment: [Transpose rows into columns in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119162/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to directly do that in SSRS ? because if I convert this through pivot, how I will assign the dynamic columns in table ?

Comment: I am not sure, Use column /Row grouping to achieve that

Comment: I got that directly in SSRS Report through matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT` to do that:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Abc])Id,* FROM
(
SELECT Name,Value FROM tbl_Questions A LEFT JOIN tbl_Reponses B ON A.Id=B.Id
) AS tbl
PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR Name IN([Abc],[Cde],[xyz],[MMM]))AS pvt
```

Or the `CrossTab` Method

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(A.Id))Id,
    [Abc] = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Abc' THEN Value END),
    [Cde] = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Cde' THEN Value END),
    [xyz] = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'xyz' THEN Value END),
    [MMM] = MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'xyz' THEN Value END)
FROM tbl_Questions A LEFT JOIN tbl_Reponses B ON A.Id=B.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

using Group by

```
select 
ID
, MIN(CASE WHEN A.NAME ='ABC'
THEN B.VALUES
END) ABC
, MIN(CASE WHEN A.NAME ='cde'
THEN B.VALUES
END) cde
, MIN(CASE WHEN A.NAME ='xyz'
THEN B.VALUES
END) xyz
, ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN A.NAME ='mmm'
THEN B.VALUES
END),'') mmm
FROM
tbl_Questions A
inner join tbl_Reponses B
on A.ID=B.ID
group by A.ID
```

Comment: the rows are not static, they can increase

Comment: unfortunately, with this approach you will need to know your row before hand for the case logic...

Comment: In that case, you would need PIVOTs with dynamic columns.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query