# Pivot in sql server returns error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for': The DUPLICATE has not the answer

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need a simple pivot on a table but keep getting errors.
The following query :

```
declare @RitID int = 21147
select RitID, BestemmingID from
(
  select eb.RitID, eb.BestemmingID 
  from   tblExtraBestemming eb
  where  eb.RitID = @RitID
) test
```

returns this result :

[image]

What I want is this :

[image]

So I looked for examples on pivot and found many, but with me they all return the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'"

This is the query i tried that gives me this error :

```
declare @RitID int = 21147
select RitID, BestemmingID from
(
  select eb.RitID, eb.BestemmingID 
  from   tblExtraBestemming eb
  where  eb.RitID = @RitID
) test  
pivot (BestemmingID for RitID in ([@RitID])) as piv
```

Is what I want possible with pivot ?
And if so can anybody help me with this query ?

**EDIT :** changed my query based on the duplicate link but still gives errors :

```
declare @RitID int = 21147
select RitID, BestemmingID from
(
  select eb.RitID, eb.BestemmingID 
  from   tblExtraBestemming eb
  where  eb.RitID = @RitID
) test  
pivot (max(BestemmingID) for RitID in ([@RitID])) as piv
```

**EDIT 2 :** tried the dynamic query from the duplicate link but it gives following error :
"The column '21147' was specified multiple times for 'p'"

here is the dynamic query i tried :

```
declare @RitID int = 21147
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(RitID) 
                    from  tblExtraBestemming
                    where RitID = @RitID 
                    group by RitID, ExtraBestemmingID
                    order by ExtraBestemmingID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select BestemmingID, RitID
                from tblExtraBestemming
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(BestemmingID)
                for RitID in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: It appears you need to use dynamic sql to generate your pivot, the duplicate ha an example of how to do this.

Comment: I have checked my querie with the examples in the duplicate link, and I corrected where neccesary but just like all other examples i have found it keep giving errors with me

Comment: It sounds like the problem is when you `select @cols` - if you print that statement do you get multiple, if so then I'd guess you need to remove `ExtraBestemmingID` from the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: I removed the ExtraBestemmingID from the groupby and orderby as you suggested, there is no more error but the result is not what I expected. It only returns 17 from my example, not 17 and 9

Comment: You'll need to utilize a windowing function like `row_number()` see my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851588/pivot-rows-to-columns-with-more-than-1-value-returned/18851868#18851868

Comment: I wrote up a little demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9e8cb/3

Comment: Thank you very much. The little demo is perfect, if you put is as an answer to the question than i will accept it as answer.